# Callback Function of setInterval is not having access to updated state if the state is updated after the interval is started

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export default function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState("");

  function handleButtonClick(value) {
    if (!active) {
      setActive(value);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setActive("");
        console.log(active);
      }, 3000);
    } else {
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(active);
        if (!active) {
          setActive(value);
          setTimeout(() => {
            setActive("");
          }, 3000);
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }, 0);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        height: "100vh",
        justifyContent: "space-between"
      }}
    >
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => handleButtonClick("first")}>first</button>
        <button onClick={() => handleButtonClick("second")}>second</button>
        <button onClick={() => handleButtonClick("third")}>third</button>
      </div>
      <div>{active.length > 0 && <p>{active} button Clicked</p>}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The callback function of setInterval in else case of handleButtonClick function is not having access to updated state, if the setInterval is started and then after that state is updated then the callback function is only having access to previous state but not updated state. How can i fix this

Required functionality
when any button is clicked the active state is set to respective value and then after 3 seconds with setTimeout the state is changed to empty string as i want it to act it as a poppup.
if another button is clicked before 3 seconds then it should wait for current 3 seocnds to complete and should show the respestive button clicked popup

Comment: required reading on exactly this kind of thing (and explaining why the behaviour you're seeing is in fact almost always what you want): https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/

Answer (score 1):

The `active` identifier that the interval callback closes over will always be the same inside the interval - it'll be that *one* `const [active ...` that was declared at the rendering where the `handleButtonClick` was created.

It looks like you want to queue up button values pressed when one is already active - consider pushing the future values to a stateful array, and use `useEffect` to move the first value in that array to the `active` state when needed. This way, you'll never be depending on values in a possibly stale closure.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState("");
  const [queue, setQueue] = useState([]);
  const toggleActive = (val) => {
    setActive(val);
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      setActive('');
    }, 3000);
    // don't forget to clean up
    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  };
  function handleButtonClick(value) {
    if (active) {
      setQueue([...queue, value]);
    } else {
      toggleActive(value);
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    // Run the next value in the queue, if active is empty and the queue is not
    if (!active && queue.length) {
      toggleActive(queue[0]);
      setQueue(queue.slice(1));
    }
  }, [active]);
  
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        height: "100vh",
        justifyContent: "space-between"
      }}
    >
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => handleButtonClick("first")}>first</button>
        <button onClick={() => handleButtonClick("second")}>second</button>
        <button onClick={() => handleButtonClick("third")}>third</button>
      </div>
      <div>{active.length > 0 && <p>{active} button Clicked</p>}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: I don't think any queue is actually needed here. From the last paragraph, it looks like the author just wants a call 3 seconds min after any change (to clean up probably). This is what debounce basically is.

Comment: i like this and it works reasonably well `useEffect` but [should not be used for chains of effects](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#chains-of-computations)

Comment: @Mulan Are you suggesting that instead of `const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => { setActive(''); }, 3000);`, the queue is checked in the timeout callback?

Comment: using `setTimeout`, it's hard to suggest something better than you have written here. i only mean to point out the `useEffect` loop (chain) that the docs suggest should be avoided. you can reference my answer for an example without effect loop.

Comment: @CertainPerformance someone copy/pasted your answer

Answer (score 0):

The required functionality is probably called 'debounce' and can be easily implemented in React using the 'useEffect' hook:

```
const [active, setActive] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setTimeout(() => setActive(''), 3000);
  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, [active]);

const handleClick = (value) => {
  setActive(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach that uses promises instead of timeout. I think you will find that the complexity is reduced. Note we are careful to avoid `setState` calls on unmounted components. See the [*You Might Not Need An Effect*](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#fetching-data) guide from React -

```js
const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState("")
  const queue = React.useRef(Promise.resolve())
  const mounted = React.useRef(true)
  React.useEffect(_ => _ => { mounted.current = false },[])
  const alert = message => event => {
    queue.current = queue.current
      .then(_ => mounted.current && setActive(message))
      .then(_ => sleep(3000))
      .then(_ => mounted.current && setActive(""))
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={alert("first")}>first</button>
      <button onClick={alert("second")}>second</button>
      <button onClick={alert("third")}>third</button>
      {active && <p>{active}</p>}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

setState (here setActive) is a async function hence updated value wont be print in console used just after it.

you can use

```
setActive(prevState => { return updatedState; }
```

here prevState will have access to updated state